# how to redirect 301 in asp.net core 2.0 (iis), add google analyze code

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

my question:

1 301 to different website

2 use google analyzer to have statistics.

i know such ideas:

> RedirectPermanent is 301 and Redirect is 302 status code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            string url = context.Request.Path.Value;

            switch (url)
            {
                case "a.localhost.com":
                    context.Response.Redirect($"http://www.aaa.com", false);
                    break;
                case "b.localhost.com":
                    context.Response.Redirect($"http://www.bbb.com", false);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
```

i want to know , how to add google analyze code?

Comment: You cannot. Google Analytics runs client-side, so after you redirect to the third-party website, it's completely out of your control at that point.

Comment: and you mean i just add statistics code by myself?

Comment: No. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, the redirect is to a third-party site you do not control. That means there is absolutely nothing you can do. Period.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, i got it .